# Intro to imaginary numbers: If $i$ = $\sqrt{-1}$ and $i^2 = -1$, then when do you use $i^2$ and when $-1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

I just am learning about complex numbers from a high school math textbook (yep, I'm playing catchup from a long time ago, as a programmer I feel that I have amazing biceps but the rest of my body is normal, time to change that).

I have watched enough YouTube videos to believe that complex numbers are real. As Eddie Woo explains: sometimes you need to dive into deeper parts of the number system in order to get solutions to 'normal problems'. Which he showed quite simply by using the quadratic formula.

But what I don't get is the following.

If $i^2 = -1$, then if I have any equation, when should I use $-1$ and when should I use $i^2$?

I suppose they're the same thing, so I should just imagine both at the same time? Just like $\sqrt-1$ and $i$ are the same thing.

Is that what you do? Imagine them both at the same time, when reading equations?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Use whatever is convenient to use at the time...  It sounds like you are asking something like "When do I use $6$ and when do I use $2\times 3$ and when do I use $1+1+1+1+1+1$?"  It depends on context.

Comment: Well $i^2$ and $-1$ are definitely the same. But $\sqrt{-1}$? Are you sure that's not $-i$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think your comment is a valid answer now that I think about it. I can easily reason about why it is the case for the example that you gave, so I suppose it's the same for my question.

Comment: @Rahul in certain contexts, yes, absolutely.  Maybe not so much for the example of $2^2$ and $4$, but $2^{10}$ and $1024$ certainly, or $2^{32}$ and $4294967296$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: $\sqrt-1$ how is that $i$? Google says: https://www.google.nl/search?source=hp&ei=2o7iXbukB8vQwALx8ZSQDA&q=sqrt%28-1%29&oq=sqrt%28-1%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l6j0i30l4.1077.2761..2980...0.0..0.54.361.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131.82dJP6yZyS8&ved=0ahUKEwi7-f6BpJLmAhVLKFAKHfE4BcIQ4dUDCAY&uact=5

Comment: @MelvinRoest whatever Google says must be true, I mean everything on the interwebs is 100% accurate. But consider this: $(-i)^2=i^2=-1$, so why should $\sqrt{-1}$ be $i$ rather than $-i$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown because it is convenient to define it to be that way.  We can define the complex numbers before having defined $i$ as being a special way of treating elements of $\Bbb R^2$ with nonstandard multiplication and division.  We can then define $i$ to be equal to the element $(0,1)$ in that context, which is clearly different than the element $(0,-1)$ in that context.  We can in such a construction avoid any ambiguity in why we might treat $\sqrt{-1}$ to be equal to $i$ and not to $-i$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think the point that Lord Shark is trying to make is "_Don't combine square root symbols and complex numbers until you're quite proficient in the subject_". Thus, for instance, _introducing_ the imaginary unit by way of $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is a big disfavor to any student. I, for the record, agree completely. As do anyone on this site who is tired of the $1 = \sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)} = -1$ question we get every once in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\sqrt{-1}$ and $i$ are *not* the same thing. Actually, since there are two square roots of $-1$, it is not a good idea to use the expression $\sqrt{-1}$, unless you defined it as something more that “square root of $-1$”.

On the other hand, I suggest that you use $i^2$ instead of $-1$ whenever that is useful. Such as when solving the equation $z^2=-1$:$$z^2=-1\iff z^2=i^2\iff z=i\vee z=-i.$$

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do. The final math statement makes it really clear as to why.

Answer (score 1):

I would hesitate to say $\sqrt{-1}$ and $i$ are the same thing. While we know that $\sqrt 3$ is the unique positive real number whose square is $3$, there's no reason to say $\sqrt{-1}$ means $i$ instead of $-i$.

However, any time two expressions represent the exact same thing you can substitute one for the other. For example, $2$ and $\sqrt4$ are completely interchangeable because they are the same number. Similarly, any place you want to use $-1$ you could use $i^2$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer in the sense that you related to the context that I knew (positive numbers) and guessed why my mental model made the mistake in the first place. You also answered my actual question. I wish I could accept both answers, it was a tough decision.

Comment: @Melvin Sure, no problem.